# Display Desktop Notication in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to display desktop notification which works only in chrome. It will be helpful if anyone help me to display notification across all browsers (firefox, ie, etc..,).

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function notify() {
  if (!window.webkitNotifications) return;  // not webKit, so no notifications available
  var havePermission = window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission();
  if (havePermission == 0) {
    var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('logo.jpg', 'Live Notification!', 'Execution Complete');
    notification.show();
  } else {
      window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
  }
}  
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div onclick="notify()">
<a href="">Cick here to get desktop notification</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `// not webKit, so no notifications available` in here lies the answer..

Comment: Thanks @adaam. I am very new to this area. It would make me understand if you could explain me in detail. Also provide me suggestion to make it display in all browsers.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification (via http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the Webkit desktop notifications implementation, so this is only going to work in browsers which support this feature. While Chrome is a webkit browser, Internet Explorer and Firefox are not based on the webkit rendering engine, so they do not support webkit desktop notifications and cannot be made to.

However, there are technologies which you could move to which have better cross browser support -- the current non-deprecated notifications API is simply called Notification. Places to read about it are the [Mozilla developer network article on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) or [here's a tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/html5-notifications). This is supported in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Is there any other way to make it work on both webkit and non-webkit browsers?

Comment: Not without moving to an API which is supported by non-webkit browsers. The API you're using is webkit only and there's no way around that. I provided links to the best alternative though.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Single notification works fine both in chrome and firefox whereas if I've multiple notifications it works onlt in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the below link related to HTML5 desktop notification API.
https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications